# Unable to update pojo class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pojo

I am trying to update my pojo class on a particular click in Kotlin but it is giving me error :-

> java.lang.stackoverflowerror: stack size 8mb

Here is my Pojo Class

```
class NavDrawerItem(var icon_normal: Int,var icon_notified: Int, var title: String, var isShowNotify: Boolean){
    var title1: String = title
        //  get() = title                    // Calls the getter recursively
        set(value)
        { title1 = value }

    var image: Int = icon_normal
        // get() = image
        set(value)
        { image = value }

    var image_notified: Int = icon_notified
        // get() = image
        set(value)
        { image_notified = value }


    var notify: Boolean = isShowNotify
        set(value) {
            notify = value
        }
}
```

I am updating my Pojo on the Item click of NavigationDrawer

```
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        mDrawerLayout?.closeDrawer(this!!.containerView!!)
        position1 = position
        for (i in navDrawerItems.indices) {
            val item = navDrawerItems[i]
            item.notify=(if (i == position) true else false)
            navDrawerItems[i] = item
            mAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

Please help me!!!!

Comment: Move `mAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` outside loop . Why don't  you use a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) for pojo.

Comment: Its not working, please share some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setters create infinite loop, which causes the `StackOverflowError` exceptions.

```
class NavDrawerItem(var icon_normal: Int,var icon_notified: Int, var title: String, var isShowNotify: Boolean){
    var title1: String = title
        //  get() = title                    // Calls the getter recursively
        set(value)
        { field = value }

    var image: Int = icon_normal
        // get() = image
        set(value)
        { field = value }

    var image_notified: Int = icon_notified
        // get() = image
        set(value)
        { field = value }


    var notify: Boolean = isShowNotify
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
}
```

The above is setting the field, where your implementation was recursively setting the values.

Also, as ADM mentioned it's better to move the notifyDataSetChanged outside of the loop and not updating at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your class as a simple [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

```
data class NavDrawerItem(var icon_normal: Int,var icon_notified: Int, var title: String, var isShowNotify: Boolean)
```

And

```
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
    mDrawerLayout?.closeDrawer(this!!.containerView!!)
    for (i in navDrawerItems.indices) {
        val item = navDrawerItems[i]
        item.notify=(i == position)
    }
    mAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use **data classes** for defining pojos.
Because data classes are only made for storing data. 
**They provides many unique features over normal class in kotlin.** 

for example, you don't need to define setter and getters, they are automatically added to your data class.

In addition, your data class will automatically override some useful functions like **equals**, **hashCode**, **toString**, and etc.

defining data class is very easy.

```
data class Foo ( val title : String, val isHungry : Boolean ){

}
```